# Call to a member function create() on null in laravel using Socialite

Tags: php, laravel

When I try to authenticate the user with using facebook so I am able to store data into the user table but the failure to create data into the soical_accounts.So after that errors with come up "call to a member funtion create() on null". Can anyone provide me solution that where I am wrong.

In my SocialAccountControll, I have the following method

```
 public function handleProviderCallback($provider)
    {
        try{

            $user = Socialite::driver($provider)->user();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
               return redirect('/login');
        }

        $authUser = $this->findOrCreateUser($user, $provider);

        Auth::login($authUser, true);

        //  redirectTo, so that way we use the same redirect location that the rest of our authentication uses.
         //This is a normal protected function that you can add in your users table to redirect a user wherever
         // you want to set that redirect to. 
        //return redirect($this->redirectTo);

        return redirect('/home');
    }

    public function findOrCreateUser($socialUser, $provider)
    {

              $account = SocialAccount::where('provider_name', $provider)->where('provider_id',$socialUser->getId())->first();

              if($account)
              {
                  return $account->user;
              }
              else
              {
                  $user = User::where('email', $socialUser->getEmail())->first();
                  if(! $user)
                  {
                      $user = User::create([
                              'email' => $socialUser->getEmail(),
                              'name' => $socialUser ->getName()
                      ]);
                  }

                  $user->accounts()->create([
                       'provider_name' => $provider,
                       'provider_id' => $socialUser->getId()
                  ]);

                  return $user;
              }


    }
```

In my database migration, I have users and social_accounts and user have one to many relationship with social_accounts.

**user table**:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->nullable();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password')->nullable();
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**Social_accounts table:**

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('social_accounts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->bigInteger('user_id');
            $table->string('provider_name')->nullable();
            $table->string('provider_id')->unique()->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

User Model 
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

```
/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];

public function accounts()
{
    $this->hasMany('App\SocialAccount');
}
```

}

SocialAccount Model

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class SocialAccount extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'provider_name', 'provider_id'
      ];

```
  public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
  }
```

}

Comment: Can you share your Models where relationship is setup?

Comment: @Iftikharuddin please check I just edited model

Comment: did you tried my answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not returning anything here so change:

```
public function accounts()
{
    $this->hasMany('App\SocialAccount');
}
```

To

```
public function accounts()
{
   return $this->hasMany('App\SocialAccount');
}
```